# Custom multi attributes in validation

Tags: laravel, validation, request, attributes

I am using validation in Request of Laravel. I would like handle a attribute base on division of another attribute. How could it control?

```
    public function rules()
    {
       return [
               'number' => 'required|numeric',
               'threshold' =>['numeric',
                  function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                   if ($attribute > 'number/2') { 
                      $fail(('threshold must be smaller than division of number'));
                        } 
                    }, ]
                ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request()` function globally all over your app,
So, in this case for accessing specific attribute you can use

```
$attribute_value = request()->YOUR_ATTRIBUTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another way of doing this using `prepareForValidation` method now available in Laravel :

In your `Request` class :

```
<?php
/**
 * Modify the input values
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function prepareForValidation(){

    $this->merge[
        'number_division_by_2' => $this->input('number') / 2
    ];
}
```

Then in your rules of the same `Request` class, you can add :

```
<?php 

public function rules()
{
   return [
           'number' => 'required|numeric',
           'threshold' =>'numeric',
           'number_division_by_2' => 'lt:threshold'
}
```